# Javascript (load e setInterval)?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma função na página index onde a `div` `#atualiza` faz um load na página home.php e se atualiza em x tempo.

index.php

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval (function()
    {$('#atualiza').load('home.php');
    cache:false;
    return false;
},60000);
```

Na página home.php eu tenho outro script para que os usuários coloquem emoticons nas postagens.

home.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.emotions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".postagem").emotions();
});

</script>
```

O problema é o seguinte ao abrir a página index pela primeira vez funciona tudo normal mas quando a div `#atualiza` se atualiza ela não lê mais o script da página home.php. Ouvi falar que o load não lê a função `ready` do jQuery, pesquisei e não achei nenhuma solução.

Como fazer a função da pagina home.php continuar executando? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Pode colocar o seu HTML para se perceber melhor a estrutura? E já agora, a página home só tem esse javascript ou tem mais?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é bem simples na verdade: a utilização do recurso `$('.postagem').emotions();` **deve ser [assíncrono](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_ass%C3%ADncrona)**.

Para resolver o seu problema, a cada vez que `div` `#atualiza` é atualizada através do método `.load()`, você deve reestabelecer a definição de `.emotions()` para `.postagem`. Para fazer isso, nós vamos mexer um pouco na forma como você atualiza a `#atualiza`. Portanto, isso aqui:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval (function()
    {$('#atualiza').load('home.php');
    cache:false;
    return false;
}, 60000);
```

Deve virar isso aqui:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval (function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'home.php',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#atualiza').html(response);
            $('.postagem').emotions();
        }
    });
}, 60000);
```

No caso, eu utilizei o método [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do jQuery para fazer uma requisição do tipo `GET` – é possível visualizar que a propriedade `TYPE` está ausente, portanto, `.ajax` assume que a requisição seja do tipo `GET` ([leia mais](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) – e a resposta (`response`) então é disponibilizada através do método [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) para a `div` `#atualiza`.

Em palavras menos técnicas, a cada vez que uma atualização é feita, o mecanismo de `.emotions()` é recarregado.

Quanto a utilização de `$('.postagem').emotions()` na marcação `$(document).ready([...]);`, você **pode** e **deve** manter, ou seja, mantenha o resto como você tem até agora e só altere o que lhe foi passado.

#### Atenção!

Você está utilizando a função `setTimeout()` para fazer uma requisição temporal e essa prática é relativamente ruim porque gera várias requisições paralelas – dependendo do número de clientes no seu site ou aplicativo – fazendo com que seja desperdiçado processamento para o tráfego de informações.

Uma opção que você tem é utilizar [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) para manter uma conexão viva entre os dois terminais da aplicação: o cliente e o servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção!!! mas continua o problema ao atualizar a pagina index nao busca a plugin de emoticon, acreito que seja pq a div .postagens esteja na pagina home e nao na index, pois e na pagina home que faz uma consulta sql e tras as postagens! vou pesquisarsobre websoquet! obrigado

Comment: Coloque isso na sua página `index.php`: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.emotions.js"></script>`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme!! descobri que o problema no final era um conflito de funções!!! abraço

Comment: @jones De nada! Poste a sua solução em formato de resposta para ajudar futuramente outros aprendizes.