# Chamar método Java no Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, java

Estou com um problema, e precisava chamar um método Java dentro de um arquivo Javascript.

Exemplo Java:

```
public void Inserir(User user)
{
    //insere usuario
}
```

Preciso, via um arquivo .js, enviar o objeto para a classe Java responsável pelo método Inserir, e realizar a inserção do usuário.

PS: Infelizmente não posso realizar via HTML, JSF, ou JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executar algum recurso JavaScript explicitamente em um aplicativo Java é impossível. Na verdade, isso não se restringe somente ao Java, mas a qualquer linguagem Server-Side com exceção de [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/), que não trabalha expressamente com o front-end.

Para solucionar o seu problema, você pode utilizar de [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). Uma forma bem simples de resolver isso é com uma solução que você mesmo propôs em um comentário de outrora: enviar dados via uma requisição HTTP no formato JSON.

Conceitualmente, o que você precisa fazer é bem simples: [serialize](http://www.json.org/java/) o conteúdo que você deseja mandar para JavaScript através de um [método Java](http://www.json.org/java/) e então, lá no front-end, em código JavaScript, você pode fazer algo assim utilizando a [biblioteca jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'localhost/user',
   success: function (response) {
       console.log(response);
   }
});
```

Sendo `url` o endereço que você disponibiliza os seus dados em JSON – através do seu aplicativo Java – e o método `success` para trabalhar com o retorno caso a requisição seja feita, sugestivamente, com sucesso.

O parâmetro `response` do método `success` são os dados pelo seu aplicativo Java enviados. A partir daí, você pode trabalhar como bem entender.

[Neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22294/javascript-load-e-setinterval/22314#22314) eu faço uma abordagem bem parecida que pode ser útil.

Comment: Valeu @Guilherme isso ajudou.

Answer (score 3):

Caro, sua missão da forma que você espera é impossível.
Mas você poderá faze-lo utilizando requisições assíncronas de forma bem simples, [veja alguns exemplos](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20webmethod%20jquery&oq=java%20webmethod%20jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9856j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Valeu... é realmente estou vendo aqui que é impossível mesmo. Vou ver esses exemplos que me enviou, obrigado.

Comment: É possível fazer a comunicação do javascript com o java via json?

Comment: @EricoSouza Bingo! Expliquei melhor na minha resposta.