# JavaScript interagir com Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, html5

É possível **pegar um valor do javascript** e colocar dentro de uma **variável em java**.

EX:

```
var len = $(" #relacaoPax select[name=tipo] ").length;
        console.log( "len = " + len );
    });
<% int l = len;
   System.out.println( "//L = " + l );
%>
```

Comment: Você precisa de AJAX, o que já é um assunto saturado. Algumas referências: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15028/popup-com-ajax-e-jquery/15081#15081 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22446/chamar-m%C3%A9todo-java-no-javascript/22464#22464

Comment: Então não possível, teria que ter um servletpara tratar esse o pedido do ajax.

Comment: Isso mesmo, Fabio. :-)

Comment: Olá.... da uma pesquisada no motor "Nashorn" eh uma forma de intreragir o JAVA com Javascript ... ou seu javaScript com o seu unix .... muito legal.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer o que você deseja porque todo o código JAVA da sua página é processado no servidor e, ao chegar no navegador só haverá código HTML e JAVASCRIPT para ser interpretado.

Comment: OK, Obrigado, vou tentar de outras formas.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisaria utilizar AJAX na sua página.

Se estiver usando JSF, dá uma olhada na tag `f:ajax`.(http://uaihebert.com/jsf-exemplos-simples-com-ajax/)

JSP + Servlet: http://www.klebermota.eti.br/2013/10/23/ajax-com-jsp-e-servlet-usando-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira rápida é fazer um campo hidden html e colocar o value lá.
Agora se for algo com muitos dados vc pode fazer uma api json  que pega os dados atráves de código js e relê-los com um rest em java.
No botão de envio tu chama a função js para enviar os dados e em seguida o que executa o backend java.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).